# Not able to add legend to the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```
ggplot(data1,aes(x= factor(treat)))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = bef_risky), stat = "summary", 
           fun = "mean", fill = "#00C1D4", 
           position = position_nudge(x = -0.125, y = 0), 
           width = 0.25, show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_bar(aes(y = aft_risky), stat = "summary", 
           fun = "mean", fill = "#FF6666", 
           position = position_nudge(x = 0.125, y = 0),
           width = 0.25, show.legend = TRUE)+
  labs(x = "treat", y = "values", 
       title = "comparison of high risky and low risky")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Female long", 
                            "2" = " Female short", 
                            "3" = "male long", 
                            "4" = "male short"))
```

Comment: This question needs a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1315767) for better understanding.

Comment: If you want a legend you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. move `fill = ...` into `aes()` and make use of e.g. `scale_fill_identity(guide = guide_legend())` to get your desired fill colors.